# Android - Add click inside text that looks all the same

Tags: android

I have a text that is multilingual and so, with different sizes. This text occupies 3 lines and is now defined in 3 separate parts, but as it is now, it is separated. I would like to have all the text in the same flow.
The problem here is that, a part in the middle of the text is clickable and I don't know how to do this without separating the text and 3 blocks and the text looks like this:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
               Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text (<--link)
of the printing and typesetting industry
```

As the text is a single flow I would like to make it all together.

Could you help me?

Thanks!

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:autoLink="web"`

put string in to resources like this:

```
    <string name="yourString">Lorem ipsum and <a href="http://example.com">link</a></string>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="@string/yourString" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txtTest.setText( Html.fromHtml(" Your Text Here <a href=\"link here">Linktexthere</a>"));
txtTest. setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```